# How to correct the resize handler changing position in text area field in BaseWeb Rect

Tags: reactjs, baseweb

When I select the text area to add text the position of resize handler changes as shown as below

[image]

It seems when in focus the text area width reduces inside the parent container of the component as shown below

[image]

How can I fix this issue

the issue is that the button on focus takes up that space and forces the text area to resize. How can I use override to access the close btn and make it position absolute so it is taken out of its context